# angular-datatables Error: Metadata version mismatch for module

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

**now Iam use**

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
node: 8.6.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.4
@angular/common: 4.4.4
@angular/compiler: 4.4.4
@angular/core: 4.4.4
@angular/forms: 4.4.4
@angular/http: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.4
@angular/router: 4.4.4
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.4
@angular/language-service: 4.4.4
typescript: 2.3.4
```

when Iam add a new pakage use npm then get my '***ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module....***
**How  posiable to slove In my current pakage.json seating or some change ?**

Answer (score 0):

If the error is for specific module run : 
    npm install @angular/"module name" --save
else you will need to get latest version of all the npm modules